# Flat File to Relational Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm receiving an input file with CustomerNumber, SalesAmt1, SalesCnt1, SalesAmt2, SalesCnt2, etc up to 4.  I have no control over my input file.  I'm trying to write an SQL statement Update that adds 4 records to the table.  Is that possible without iterating through the file?  I would appreciate any help at all.

Comment: I recommend loading the data into a staging table and doing the transformation in the database.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff  I can do four insert statements then - one for each SalesAmt/Cnt pair.  Good thinking!

Comment: Write a tiny stored procedure with the 4 statements and any key info you require, that way you can do this in 1 go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert into a staging table.  Then you can inset the data using `outer apply`:

```
insert into newtable (customernumber, salescnt, salesamt)
    select v.*
    from staging s outer apply
         (values (s.customernumber, s.salescnt1, s.salesamt1),
                 (s.customernumber, s.salescnt2, s.salesamt2),
                 (s.customernumber, s.salescnt3, s.salesamt3),
                 (s.customernumber, s.salescnt4, s.salesamt4)
         ) v(customernumber, salescnt, salesamt);
```

Comment: That is flipping genius!